# Agregar mapa de google con marca de Punto (longitud,latitud)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps

quiero agregar en mi pagina ASP.NET un mapa con una marca , este codigo me agrega el mapa pero no el punto , que sera lo que estoy haciendo Mal??

```
   function CreateMapGoogle() {

            var atrMap = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.712449, -74.001508),
                zoom: 14,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("idgoogleMap"), atrMap);
            var myLatLng = { lat: 40.712449, lng: -74.001500};
            var i=0;

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                    icon: 'x.png',
                    title: 'MI TITULO',
                    position: myLatLng
                });
                marker.setMap(map);
                (function (marker, i) {

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {

                        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ maxWidth: 250 });
                        infowindow.setContent('MI UBICACION NOMBRE');
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);

                    });

                })(marker, i);

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que veo es que asignas el `map` al `Marker` pero tambien realizas el `setMap()`, cuando deberia ser una u otra forma no ambas

[Marcadores](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers?hl=es)

si usas el setMap() solo usas este

```
var myLatLng = { lat: 40.712449, lng: -74.001500};

var atrMap = {
            center: myLatLng,
            zoom: 4
        };

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("idgoogleMap"), atrMap);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    icon: 'x.png',
    title: 'MI TITULO',
    position: myLatLng
});

marker.setMap(map);
```

tambien analiza el ejemplo

[Simple markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple?hl=es)

intenta quitando la parte del `addListener` para ver si esta esta generando un error en javascript que impide que el marker se represente